# Firebase Test Lab can't record page scroll event in script recording

Tags: android, firebase, testing, firebase-test-lab

I'am trying to record a script. Every things is ok but when I try to scroll page, recorder is not responding and record nothing. I tried that in page with RecyclerView and ScrollView.

When I looked at test result in firebase console and watched the video, when the script is over and start the random test, pages can scrolling. So I thing there is a way but I can't find what it is. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Page scrolling is not recorded as a separate event. For example, if you scroll a RecyclerView and then click on an item, your click will be recorded and then, during replay of the script, both your scroll and your click will be replayed.